# Using data type other than int as index value in C++ for loop

Tags: c++, c, loops, type-conversion

I am accepting an input from user as a float value.

This value can go up to "10 raised to power 18".

The next step involves finding all the divisors of this number. for which i am doing the following:

```
      for(i=2; i<=n/2 ; i++)
      {
        if(n%i==0) 
           v.push_back(i);
      }
```

Here, n is the number entered by the user.

Problem is that n is float and using it in if loop index causes it's value to be limited to '10 raised to the power 9'

Hence, is there any way to use data type other than int for using values of range '10 raised to power 18'?

Comment: Does your compiler support 64-bit integers, using perhaps `long long`?

Comment: By definition floats don't have divisors, actually.  However if you want an integer-like mod you could use `fmod`

Comment: @hroptatyr: Er, yes, floats can have divisors, because they can represent integers.  (Otherwise you couldn't factor numbers in JavaScript, because all numbers are floats in JavaScript.)

Comment: @AmanKejriwal: `printf("%d\n", sizeof(long long));` would confirm it. If you get an error, then your compiler doesn't understand `long long`. If you get a result of 8, then your compiler's `long long` integers are 64 bits.

Comment: By the way,  if you expect to have large n here, how long are you going to wait for your loop to finish? With n > 10^15 it may take days.

Comment: @DietrichEpp you're right, what I was trying to say is that factorisation makes no sense for floats, as all numbers (but 0) are divisors to any float

Comment: @hroptatyr: That's true for real numbers, but not for floating point numbers, and it's beside the point.  If you use a float to represent an integer, you can factor it as an integer.  You're not forced to factor it as a float just because that's the representation you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `unsigned long long` which is 2<sup>64</sup> or roughly 10<sup>19</sup>

This assumes that your compiler supports 64-bit integers.

Comment: I added the "to the power" tag for you :)

Comment: Hi, using unsigned long long on n, the input value is fine. But, when I do i = n/2, the value of i is limited to the int range. I have also declared i as unsigned long long but it is not helping

Comment: Also I think you'd need to speciy 2 as a ULL. i.e `i = n / 2ULL`

Answer (score 2):

The question has been answered (use long long int), but wanted to point out that floats are called "floating point" for a reason. They incorporate an exponent, basically the position of the decimal point, which determines the precision of the mantissa. This conveniently allows you to both represent small numbers with high precision and large numbers with low precision, **but not both at the same time**.

For more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Try this:

```
int main(void)
{
    float i = 16777217.0f;
    printf("i = %f\n", i);
    i++;
    printf("i+1 = %f\n", i);
}
```

w/ 32-bit floats this returns:

```
i = 16777216.000000
i+1 = 16777216.000000
```

So question of the day: what do you think will happen if you have a loop like this?

```
for(float f; f < 20000000; ++f) 
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a long double should be substantial.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use other data types for loop , use any of the types mentioned  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)